# Как получить комбинацию элементов по списку списков по 2 элемента на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить комбинацию элементов такого списка по 2 элементам из каждого подсписка. Дано:

```
from itertools import product

list1 = [[['a1', 66],['a2', 58],['a3', 56]],
         [['b1', 66],['b2', 49],['b3', 51],['b4', 58]],
         [['c1', 66],['c2', 53],['c3', 50]],
         [['x1', 66],['x2', 53],['x3', 50]]     
       ]
```

Чтобы получить из каждого подсписка все комбинации состоящие из одного элемента из каждого подсписка я делаю вот так:

```
list_product = list(product(*list1))
print(list_product)
>>>[(['a1', 66], ['b1', 66], ['c1', 66], ['x1', 66]),
    (['a1', 66], ['b1', 66], ['c1', 66], ['x2', 53]),
    (['a1', 66], ['b1', 66], ['c1', 66], ['x3', 50]),
    (['a1', 66], ['b1', 66], ['c2', 53], ['x1', 66]),
     .....
     (['a3', 56], ['b4', 58], ['c3', 50], ['x3', 50])]
```

Но мне нужно чтобы из каждого подсписка бралось по 2 элемента, чтобы в итоге было вот так:

```
print(list_product)
>>>[(['a1', 66], ['a2', 58], ['b1', 66], ['b2', 49], ['c1', 66], ['c2', 53], ['х1', 66], ['х2', 53]),
    (['a1', 66], ['a2', 58], ['b1', 66], ['b2', 49], ['c1', 66], ['c2', 53], ['х1', 66], ['х3', 50]),
   ....
    (['a2', 58], ['a3', 56], ['b3', 51], ['b4', 58], ['c2', 53], ['c3', 50], ['х2', 53], ['х3', 50])]
```

Comment: почему последний элемент ['x3', 50], а не ['x2', 53]?

Comment: Непонятно логику чего вы хотите достичь, думаю вопрос лучше дополнить

Comment: потому что я в вопросе выводил print(list_product[1]) первый индекс, а не [0], исправил вопрос

Comment: @DiMithras я не знаю как более понятно вопрос задать, мне нужно чтобы из каждого подсписка бралось по 2 элемента и на выход мы получили все возможные комбинации

Comment: @ChikChirik я во втором кодовом блоке не вижу комбинаций, вы просто берёте два элемента и пропускаете третий. Ну а после дополнения вопроса пропускаете первый элемент и берёте два после него.

Comment: @DiMithras дополнил вопрос, так лучше?)

Comment: В итоге в чём комбинации заключаются? В пропуске 1-его, 2-ого, 3-его элемента?

Comment: Возможно, просто здесь я привел небольшой пример, в реальной задаче каждый подсписок состоит не из 3 элементов и не всегда из количество в подсписках одинаково, вот в чем проблема

Comment: В общем, вам бы расписать **подробно** логику или даже нарисовать, лично я не понимаю чего вы хотите. И вместо **2** лучше пишите по 2-ум / 2-ым, иначе слишком ambiguous.

Comment: @DiMithras вы понимаете, что дает вот этот код? list_product = list(product(*list1)), далее мне нужно также получать комбинации все, но уже чтобы из каждого подсписка бралось по 2, а не по 1 элементу

Comment: @ChikChirik декартово произведение, вы то что хотите?

Comment: @ChikChirik тогда смотрите ответ **gimntut**, очень похоже на то что вы ищете

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import product, combinations

list1 = [[['a1', 66],['a2', 58],['a3', 56]],
         [['b1', 66],['b2', 49],['b3', 51]],
         [['c1', 66],['c2', 53],['c3', 50]],
         [['x1', 66],['x2', 53],['x3', 50]]     
       ]
list_product = list(product(*[combinations(x,2) for x in list1]))
print(list_product)
```

Решение не полное. Сам не проверял.
Просто пример того, в какую сторону нужно копать

Comment: Да, оно, спасибо большое!

Comment: @ChikChirik добавьте в вопрос вывод `list_product[0:2]`, потому что по вопросу, повторюсь, очень непонятно что вы хотели, вы же не указали кортежи на два элемента.